# MagicDraw fork component flashed red and terminated my simulation

Tags: magic-draw

I'm running a simulation on the MagicDraw 2022x SysML Activity diagram here and when it gets to the fork (that is connected with a join after just two actions) it just flashes red and terminates the simulation: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28vD9.png)

I'm not well versed in MagicDraw and I only tried moving a merge diamond ahead of the fork so I'm out of ideas.